# Does JSON grammar allow bare labels for elements? and are single quotes allowed?

Tags: json, string, label, grammar

After examining the JSON.org railroad (grammar) definition, it appears that the label and value pair for an element ( label : value ) requires quotes around the labels.  Are quotes required always, or are they allowed to be omitted from simple words?

Example - this appears to be legal,

```
{ "vehicle" : { "type" : "truck", "year" : 1954, "make" : "ford" } }
```

Example - would this be legal?

```
{ vehicle : { type : "truck", year : 1954, make : "ford" } }
```

Also, are single quotes (') allowed, or only double quotes (")?  Example,

```
{ 'vehicle' : { 'type' : 'truck', 'year' : 1954, 'make' : 'ford' } }
```

Many languages allow labels to be bare, and Ruby (for example) allows symbols to be prefixed by colon (:), example,

```
:fruit
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, according to the [official JSON spec](http://json.org/) double quotes (and only double quotes) are required around every string, including object keys.

This is just one reason why JSON is a **subset** of the Javascript object literal notation, not a complete implementation.

Comment: Having done a fair bit of javascript, perl, and ruby, I would think JSON would allow 'bare' tags/labels for a more flexible (simpler?) syntax.

Comment: I would assume they did it this way to giver a stricter, less error-prone set of rules by which to validate string data.

Comment: While rechecking the JSON spec (as part of providing meta data to a web api that wants JSON), it occured to me that JSON could have been spec'ed to not require quotes :-)

Comment: Yeah they could have (you may even find non-conforming JSON parsers in which unquoted keys will parse without error) but the JSON spec would have required a different set of rules for keys then. I think being so simple is one of JSON's strengths, even if it does require a few extra bytes to pass the same data.

Comment: Having built a few DSL's. I would think allowing 'bare' tags/labels or allowing both single and double quotes would have cost little for complexity, and added flexibility (my $.02).

Answer (score 0):

JSON syntax is a subset of the JavaScript object notation syntax:
•Data is in name/value pairs
•Data is separated by commas
•Curly braces hold objects
•Square brackets hold arrays

I think - http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp will calrify your questions.

Comment: Not all data is in name/value pairs. An array of numbers is valid.